# Recursive function for reading file in Python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, file, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive function in Python to read file. The file has kind of tree structure. User will input the first file name. The file will contain the list of other files. If the line starts with '+' it means the followed line after + symbol is another file name which we have to read. If it does not starts with + symbol then we have to print that line.
Below code is not working in recursive manner.

```
 def readFile(myfile):
 print("FUnctionEntered\n",myfile)
 fileOpen=open(myfile,'r')
 for line in fileOpen:
            if line.startswith('+'):
                    myfile=[line.lstrip('+') for line in fileOpen]
                    line.rstrip()
                    print(line,"\n")
                    readFile(line)
            else:
                    print line
 fileOpen.close()
 return line
```

Comment: What does not work? Any errors, or which file(s) are not printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
def readFile(filename):
    print("Reading file: %s" % (filename))
    f=open(filename,'r').readlines()
    for i in f:
        if i.startswith('+'):
            readFile(i[1:].rstrip())
        else:
            print(i)
```

Read in all the lines at once and then run through them with the for loop. If it starts with '+', the filename is the string starting from the second character `i[1:]` and we strip off the new line with `.rstrip()` as before. If it doesn't start with '+' then just print. There is no need to return anything is you're not doing anything with it apparently.

Be careful with recursive functions like this. They can quite easily run off forever if something unforeseen happens. Good luck!